# Android DatePickerDialog from Spinner

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker, spinner

I'm using a DatePickerDialog I open via button. How can I open them in a spinner?

```
 public void chooseDate(View v) {
new DatePickerDialog(Movimenti.this, d,
                      dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                     dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                      dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
  .show();
```

}
    private void updateLabel() {

```
  mDataScelta.setText(fmtDateAndTime.format(dateAndTime.getTime()));
```

}

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                      int dayOfMonth) {
  dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
  dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
  dateAndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
  updateLabel();
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Comment: How do I insert it in my Activity?